# How to get callback from AndroidX VideoCapture for every second recorded

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

Is it possible to get a callback for every second or frame recorded using `androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture`?

For now I can start a runnable at the `videoCapture.startRecording` callback, but it is not 100% precise. I need to save som data that should be synchronized with the video so its necessary that the video and data is aligned in time.

My code so far:

```
videoCapture.startRecording(
    new VideoCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(currentVideo).build(),
    getExecutor(),
    new VideoCapture.OnVideoSavedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onVideoSaved(@NonNull VideoCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Recording ended");
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(int videoCaptureError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {
        }
    }
);

Log.i(TAG,"Recording started");

Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
final Runnable everySecond = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        Log.i(TAG,"Tick");
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(everySecond, 0);
```